# How to open and close chrome tab using .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat file which only opens chrome, and I want to close the tab it opened after a while.

This is my original code:

```bash
start cmd /c "start chrome.exe "http://localhost/home.php"
```

I want to add this line, `timeout /t 200 taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T > nul`, so...

```bash
start cmd /c "start chrome.exe "http://localhost/home.php" timeout /t 200 taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T > nul
```

but the result is it opens a tab name `timeout`,`taskkill` and `chrome.exe`.

[image: opened tabs]

What am I doing wrong? How do I edit the code? Do I add a quote for each task?

Comment: A batch file is processed by the *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe`. The command `start` is an internal command of `cmd.exe` which calls the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) with a
[STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure for running another executable as detached, separate and parallel executed process which shares nothing with `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to use the command `start` to run one more `cmd.exe` as parallel executed process just to start `chrome.exe` with a url as first argument. `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe` are two more [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands). These are external Windows commands as being executables in the Windows system directory instead of internal commands of `cmd.exe`. The useless command line posted by you passes them as arguments to `chrome.exe`.

Comment: The batch file should have four command lines. The first one is `@echo off` to turn off the command echo mode. The second command line should be `start "" chrome.exe "http://localhost/home.php"` for starting *Chrome* with the url as argument. There are lots of options offered by `chrome.exe` to control how *Chrome* is started. Find the documentation about the *Chrome* command line options using a www search engine, read the documentation and use those of interest for your task between the file name `chrome.exe` and the url.

Comment: The third command line in the batch file should be `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 200 >nul` for waiting 200 seconds. Run in a command prompt window `echo /?`, `start /?`, `timeout /?` and `taskkill /?` for output of the usage help of each used Windows command and read the helps. The fourth and last command line could be `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /IM chrome.exe /T >nul` which gracefully __terminates__ *ALL* running `chrome.exe` processes with their child processes instead of a forced brutal __kill__ of all *Chrome* processes by the operating system.

Comment: Never use __TASKKILL__ with its option `/F` for `chrome.exe`. A forced brutal kill by the operating system is not necessary for *Chrome* because of *Chrome* handles the [WM_CLOSE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) sent to each running *Chrome* process on __not__ using option `/F` resulting in a graceful self-termination with stopping running transfers, closing all internet connections, saving unsaved data to files and Windows registry, closing all currently opened files and finally exiting the process. All that cannot be done by *Chrome* on using `/F`.

Comment: The usage of the command operator `&` as described by [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) is not necessary at all. A batch file can contain multiple commands on multiple command lines. There is absolutely no need making the task more complex by putting all commands on a single command line although possible too. There is also really no need to start one more `cmd.exe` using `CreateProcess` just to let it use `CreateProcess` for starting `chrome.exe`.

Comment: `timeout.exe` and `taskkill.exe` are also started using `CreateProcess` by `cmd.exe`. The difference is that `cmd.exe` instructs `CreateProcess` to start these two Windows console applications without creating a new console window and with using `stdin` (standard input), `stdout` (standard output) and `stderr` (standard error) of `cmd.exe` processing the batch file and with `cmd.exe` waiting on self-termination of the started executable before opening the batch file again for reading next command line, parsing it, closing the batch file and executing the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
start cmd /c "start chrome.exe http://localhost/home.php" & timeout /t 200 & taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T > nul
```

use & to chain multiple commands together

Comment: This will kill every chrome process on the system. Including other, preexisting tabs, that you haven't even started.

Comment: thanks! @Sean 's did the work. I did not know you have to put the & there. There is no other tabs that will be open on the browser so this solution is okay.